# Is there a way to take multiple date intervals in sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I run this bit of code in SQL and would like to get data for a certain duration of time.
Here 40min every hour, could be 10min for example;
The idea is to get snapshots of shorter timeframe
It works with 1 interval but when you go above like here, it doesn't work anymore

The query output : 'There is no data to display'.

```
SELECT *
FROM `xxxx.yyyy.data` 
WHERE 
executedAt > "2022-05-18 12:00:00"
AND executedAt < "2022-05-18 12:40:00"
AND executedAt > "2022-05-18 13:00:00"
AND executedAt < "2022-05-18 13:40:00"
AND executedAt > "2022-05-18 14:00:00"
AND executedAt < "2022-05-18 14:40:00"
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you this will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM `xxxx.yyyy.data` 
WHERE 
(executedAt > '2022-05-18 12:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 12:40:00') OR
(executedAt > '2022-05-18 13:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 13:40:00') OR
(executedAt > '2022-05-18 14:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 14:40:00')
```

Comment: Thank you this works well alone; if I try to add a filter with 'AND' it shows me this error : Cannot query over table 'xxxx.yyyy.data' without a filter over column(s) 'executedAt' that can be used for partition elimination. `AND currency1 = 'XYZ'`

Comment: U are welcome , try this. You should learn how it works AND & OR operators.
SELECT * 
FROM `xxxx.yyyy.data` 
WHERE 
 currency1 = 'XYZ' AND ((executedAt > '2022-05-18 12:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 12:40:00') OR
(executedAt > '2022-05-18 13:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 13:40:00') OR
(executedAt > '2022-05-18 14:00:00' AND executedAt < '2022-05-18 14:40:00'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).